# Is there a way to view statistics about visitors by country?

Tags: support, statistics, data, data-explorer

I was wondering if there is some sort of a counter or statistics about registered / unregistered visitors of ask ubuntu by world region or country, in a certain given time period and / or site activity.

I know [SE data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) allows the creation of queries about every SE community, but it only gathers data on site components.
For example, the query below lists users by reputation of a given "country", but it actually matches the input string to whatever is written at the "location" tab in all community users' profile.

This means that if a user hasn't written anything in their profile, or wrote something like "Wonderland", they won't appear:

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
Id AS [User Link], 
Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    LOWER(Location) LIKE LOWER('%##CountryName##%')
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

Comment: No, for privacy reasons we only have access to what users offer in their Location field in their profile. Stack Exchange might have data per user from which country their IP traffic originates. That data might give them a better idea about visitors by country but this still is data is not public available.

Comment: I have a somewhat more elaborate query to get more useful data from the location field mapped to a country here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348235/158100

Comment: Even if there's a way to know their IP addresses, they are not 100% accurate since users are allowed to use a VPN.

Comment: this is less about showing us their ip addresses, and more about just knowing where most of the traffic comes from for registered and unregistered users. No intend to expose registered user's location. mainly raw statistics.